# Export only subset of methods implemented by embedded struct

Tags: go, methods, struct, embedding

Is it possible to export only a subset of methods implemented by an embedded struct?
Is this a very go-unlike way to reduce copy - and - pasting of code and there is a more idiomatic way to do this?

```
type A struct {
}

func (a *A) Hello() {
    fmt.Println("Hello!")
}

func (a *A) World() {
    fmt.Println("World!")
}

type B struct {
    A
}

type C struct {
    A
}

func main() {
    b := B{}
    c := C{}

    // B should only export the Hello - function
    b.Hello()

    // C should export both Hello - and World - function
    c.Hello()
    c.World()
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how embedding works, there's nothing you can do about it. *(Actually there is, see dirty trick at the end.)*

What you want may be achieved with interfaces though. Make your structs unexported, (`B` => `b` and `C` => `c`), and create "constructor" like functions, which return interface types, containing only the methods you wish to publish:

```
type b struct {
    A
}

type c struct {
    A
}

type Helloer interface {
    Hello()
}

type HelloWorlder interface {
    Helloer
    World()
}

func NewB() Helloer {
    return &b{}
}

func NewC() HelloWorlder {
    return &c{}
}
```

You might want to call the interfaces and functions different, this is just for demonstration.

Also note that while the returned `Helloer` interface does not include the `World()` method, it is still possible to "reach" it using [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions), e.g.:

```
h := NewB() // h is of type Helloer
if hw, ok := h.(HelloWorlder); ok {
    hw.World() // This will succeed with the above implementations
}
```

Try this on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/reRB7l1z7n).

### Dirty trick

If a type embeds the type `A`, (fields and) methods of `A` that get *promoted* will become part of the [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) of the embedder type (and thus become methods of type `A`). This is detailed in [Spec: Struct types:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types)

> A field or [method](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations) `f` of an anonymous field in a struct `x` is called *promoted* if `x.f` is a legal [selector](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors) that denotes that field or method `f`.

The focus is on the *promotion*, for which the selector must be **legal**. [Spec: Selectors](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors) describes how `x.f` is resolved:

> The following rules apply to selectors:
>
> 1. For a value `x` of type `T` or `*T` where `T` is not a pointer or interface type, `x.f` denotes the field or method at the shallowest depth in `T` where there is such an `f`. If there is not exactly [`one f`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Uniqueness_of_identifiers) with shallowest depth, the selector expression is illegal.
>
> [...]

What does this mean? Simply by embedding, `B.World` will denote the `B.A.World` method as that is at the shallowest depth. But if we can *achieve* so that `B.A.World` won't be the shallowest, the type `B` won't have this `World()` method, because `B.A.World` won't get promoted.

How can we achieve that? We may add a field with name `World`:

```
type B struct {
    A
    World int
}
```

This `B` type (or rather `*B`) will not have a `World()` method, as `B.World` denotes the *field* and not `B.A.World` as the former is at the shallowest depth. Try this on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0umHLGO7EP).

Again, this does not prevent anyone to explicitly refer to `B.A.World()`, so that method can be "reached" and called, all we achieved is that the type `B` or `*B` does not have a `World()` method.

Another variant of this "dirty trick" is to exploit the end of the first rule: *"If there is **not exactly one** `f` with shallowest depth"*. This can be achieved to also embed another type, another struct which also has a `World` field or method, e.g.:

```
type hideWorld struct{ World int }

type B struct {
    A
    hideWorld
}
```

Try this variant on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/p82ttZWb8W).

Comment: Would it be better to declare `World` as `struct{}` instead of `int`?

Comment: @zhangyoufu Whatever type will work, what matters is the name of the field. Size of `struct{}` is zero, so it may be better to use that. The examples here are just a demonstration.