# How to make embedded generic field unexported

Tags: go, generics, struct

If I don't use generics, I can use this code below,

```
type otherType = external.OtherType
type MyType struct {
    otherType 
}
```

but if I use generics, It can't work, because generic type cannot be alias.

```
type otherType[T any] = external.OtherType[T] //error, generic type cannot be alias
type MyType[T any] struct {
    otherType[T]
}
```

I want to "overide" a method of a generic type,but I don't want all methods of the embedded field to export.

Comment: Write an adapter.

Comment: what is the purpose of embedding here? If you want to "override" one method of `OtherType` and hide all the others, then there's no relation between `MyType` and `OtherType`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be available in the not-so-distant future: [spec: generics: permit type parameters on aliases](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/46477), the proposal is already accepted.

As of today (Go 1.20) you can only define type aliases on instantiations of generic types:

```
type otherType = external.OtherType[string]
```

However note that methods of an embedded type get promoted even if the type itself is unexported. What you accomplish by embedding an unexported type is simply to prevent client packages to access the embedded **field**.

For some workaround, see [Export only subset of methods implemented by embedded struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439087/export-only-subset-of-methods-implemented-by-embedded-struct).